# Does AIP GET need to have a request message

Tags: protocol-buffers, proto, google-ai-platform

It's confusing when reading the docs for AIP Get. https://google.aip.dev/131 First, they did not define what are the verbs used mean. What does "Must", "Should", "May", etc... mean. In general, they did not specify if a Request Message is needed or not, but they stated that "The URI should contain a single variable field corresponding to the resource name". Does this imply that it's just a recommendation to have a variable? And that you can have a GET without a variable? Second, if it imply it's a recommendation, does it mean it's allowed you can have a GET method API with an empty param `google.protobuf.Empty`?
Our use case is where the param for the API would be the current user, which we will get from the service context rather than having to add it as a parameter.

Comment: This is defined in API-8: https://google.aip.dev/8#:~:text=third%20heading%20levels%20(%23%23%2C%20%23%23%23).-,Requirement%20keywords,-AIPs%20should%20use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. MUST   This word, or the terms "REQUIRED" or "SHALL", mean that the
   definition is an absolute requirement of the specification.
2. MUST NOT   This phrase, or the phrase "SHALL NOT", mean that the
   definition is an absolute prohibition of the specification.
3. SHOULD   This word, or the adjective "RECOMMENDED", mean that there
   may exist valid reasons in particular circumstances to ignore a
   particular item, but the full implications must be understood and
   carefully weighed before choosing a different course.
4. SHOULD NOT   This phrase, or the phrase "NOT RECOMMENDED" mean that
   there may exist valid reasons in particular circumstances when the
   particular behavior is acceptable or even useful, but the full
   implications should be understood and the case carefully weighed
   before implementing any behavior described with this label.
5. MAY   This word, or the adjective "OPTIONAL", mean that an item is
   truly optional.  One vendor may choose to include the item because a
   particular marketplace requires it or because the vendor feels that
   it enhances the product while another vendor may omit the same item.
   An implementation which does not include a particular option MUST be
   prepared to interoperate with another implementation which does
   include the option, though perhaps with reduced functionality. In the
   same vein an implementation which does include a particular option
   MUST be prepared to interoperate with another implementation which
   does not include the option (except, of course, for the feature the
   option provides.)

So all the statements that contain "must" are mandatory the others are not.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Is there any reference to it? The definitions seems right to me, but I was looking for a resource.

Comment: You can read more about this here https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2119